# Mongoose autopopulate on create

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm using the mongoose plugin `autopopulate` to populate docs from a separate collection. Here's a dumbed down schema:

```
const PostSchema = new Schema(
  {
    user: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'user',
      required: true,
      autopopulate: {
        select: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'username']
      }
    },
    comment: { type: String }
  }
)
```

Now, when I create a post with

```
const post = await Post.create({ user, comment });
```

It returns null for the populated user even though it shows up in the database and subsequent queries. I've used the `{ new: true }` option on `findByIdAndUpdate` but it doesn't seem to work on `create`. Any thoughts on how to get create to return the populated docs?